# The JWT received after authentication is not immediately valid

Tags: auth0, symfony-2.8

I'm using Symfony 2.8, `auth0/jwt-auth-bundle` (version 1.2) and `nelmio/cors-bundle` (version 1.4.1).

The issue I'm having is when the active user logs out and logs back in, the new token I received from Auth0 is not automatically active; I have to wait up to one minute before making calls using the received JWT. If I used it immediately everything returns 500 error (using postman or my app to test).

After approximately one minute, without doing anything, it becomes active and calls start giving 200 response status.

Why I'm I having this delay? I need the token to be active as soon as the user logs in. Am I missing some configuration?

Here are my settings:

```
jwt_auth:
    domain:      "domain.com"
    client_id:     "%client_id%"
    client_secret: "%client_secret%"
    secret_base64_encoded: "%secret_base64_encoded%"


nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: []
        allow_headers: []
        allow_methods: []
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 0
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: true
    paths:
        '^/api':
            allow_credentials: true
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
            expose_headers: []
            max_age: 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided the most likely cause of the problem would be a clock skew between the server issuing the JWT (Auth0) and the server validating the JWT (your application).

Check [this documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/connector/troubleshooting#clock-skew) for more information about clock skew and what to do about it (the documentation page is associated with the Auth0 AD Connector library, but clock skew is a general problem).

> This can be fixed by ensuring that the System is properly configured to use to pool a sync server via the NTP (Network Time Protocol).

You can also confirm if this is indeed the problem by decoding the received JWT in [https://jwt.io/] and checking its lifetime related claims `exp`, `nbf` and/or `iat`.